# Handling Categorical Data with Many Values in sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I am trying to predict customer retention with a variety of features.

One of these is org_id which represents the organization the customer belongs to. It is currently a float column with numbers ranging from 0.0 to 416.0 and 417 unique values.

I am wondering what the best way of preprocessing this column is before feeding it to a scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier. Generally, I would one-hot-encode categorical features, but there are so many values here so it would radically increase my data dimensionality. I have 12,000 rows of data, so I might be OK though, and only about 10 other features.

The alternatives are to leave the column with float values, convert the float values to int values, or convert the floats to pandas' categorical objects.

Any tips are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org_id` does not seem to be a feature that brings any info for the classification, you should drop this value and not pass it into the classifier.

In a classifier you only want to pass features that are discriminative for the task that you are trying to perform: here the elements that can impact the retention or churn. The ID of a company does not bring any valuable information in this context therefore it should not be used.

**Edit following OP's comment:**

Before going further let's state something: with respect to the number of samples (12000) and the relative simplicity of the model, one can make multiple attempts to try different configurations of features easily.

So, As a baseline, I would do as I said before, drop this feature all together. Here is your baseline score i.e., a score you can compare your other combinations of features against.

I think it cost nothing to try to hot-encode `org_id`, whichever result you observe is going to add up to your experience and knowledge of how the Random Forest behaves in such cases. As you only have 10 more features, the Boolean features `is_org_id_1`, `is_org_id_2`, ... will be highly preponderant and the classification results may be highly influenced by these features.

Then I would try to reduce the number of Boolean features by finding new features that can "describe" these 400+ organizations. For instance, if they are only US organizations, their state which is ~50 features, or their number of users (which would be a single numerical feature), their years of existence (another single numerical feature). Let's note that these are only examples to illustrate the process of creating new features, only someone knowing the full problematic can design these features in a smart way.

Also, I would find interesting that, once you solve your problem, you come back here and write another answer to your question as I believe, many people run into such problems when working with real data :)

Comment: thanks for the response. I understand your point, and it is a good one. But I have 2 points in response: 1) Assuming that org_id does bring info for classification, how would you handle it? i.e. how do I solve this issue in general?; 2) I'm not actually trying to predict retention per se, but am trying to identify which factors in my dataset predict future user retention. My idea is to create a Random Forest Classifier for this data and then get feature importances from the classifier so I can identify which factors predict future user retention.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. To summarize your points, I have 3 options: 1) drop the column; 2) one-hot-encode it; 3) come up with other features other than id. Good suggestions. I should mention that I'm not working on a 'real' problem since this is a take-home challenge dataset and I do not have access to organizational data other than org_id. So I can't do 3. From my own reading, I think binning is the standard approach to dealing with high-cardinality categorical data (e.g. zip codes). So I could try binning my orgs. The issue there is I don't know if that works for nominal data.

Comment: As opposed to ordinal data where there is a notion of bigger/smaller/order among the data values. In this case, one org_id is the same as any other, even if some are 'larger' than others.

Comment: Your last comment is the very reason why this type of data is often complex to deal with when the number of category is big.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look at my data and see if any binning pattern suggests itself to me. For example, if a third of the rows have org_id 0, a third have org_id 1, and the last third has org_ids 2 through 416, then 3 bins would be best. Obviously, I don't think my data will be this simple. So I'll probably just end up leaving the column as is. I don't want to drop it because I'm looking to see if there's any feature importance at all with it, and it would defeat my purpose to drop it. And like  you said, I think one-ho-encoding would overwhelm the other features.